# What is the mechanism behind Gnu C++ 4.8 thread_local implementation and what exact "runtime penalty" is there?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, thread-local, gcc4.8

The gcc 4.8.0 added the implementation of  `thread_local` from the C++11 Standard.
The [Changes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) state that there may be a "runtime penally":

> G++ now implements the C++11 `thread_local` keyword; [...] Unfortunately, this support **requires a run-time penalty for references to non-function-local `thread_local` variables defined in a different translation unit even if they don't need dynamic initialization**, [...].
>
> If the programmer can be sure that no use of the variable in a non-defining TU needs to trigger dynamic initialization (either because the variable is statically initialized, or a use of the variable in the defining TU will be executed before any uses in another TU), they can avoid this overhead with the -fno-extern-tls-init option.

Can anyone explain to me what G++ does for `thread_local` global variables?

- What is the general mechanism?
- What induces the overhead?
- How much overhead is involved per access? A pointer indirection? A costly lock?
- Under what circumstances is there no overhead, exactly?

From the changes note I assume for example that this would not have overhead:

```
thread_local Data data { 1000 };

void worker() {
    for(auto &elem : data)
        elem.calulcate();
}
```

because `data` is in the same translation unit?

And how does this change if `worker` and `data` are in different translation units? Is this an example for that?

```
// module.cpp

void worker();

thread_local Data data { 1000 };

void start() {
    worker();
}

// main.cpp

extern thread_local Data data; // correct decl?

void worker() {
    for(auto &elem : data)
        elem.calulcate();
}
```

Does now the use of `data` in `worker` induce an overhead? Is that still the case, even it it was `start` that kicked off `worker`?